# Problem with installing the rjsoncons library in R

Tags: r, rcpp11, jsoncons

I have tried to install rjsoncons in R but encountered errors. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and have previously ran

```
    sudo apt install libjsoncpp-dev
```

such that libjsoncpp-dev is already the newest version (1.7.4-3).

These are the error messages I received when I tried to install rjsoncons library in R, and the errors relates to reference to the cpp11 library ‘writable’ being ambiguous.

```
    install.packages("rjsoncons", repos = "https://CRAN.R-project.org")
```

```
**Installing package into ‘/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
**# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
**trying URL 'https://CRAN.R-project.org/src/contrib/rjsoncons_1.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 578073 bytes (564 KB)
**# ==================================================**
**downloaded 564 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rjsoncons’ ...
** package ‘rjsoncons’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0’
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I'/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include'     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-WnOgSi/r-base-4.3.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c cpp11.cpp -o cpp11.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I'/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include'     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-WnOgSi/r-base-4.3.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c rjsoncons.cpp -o rjsoncons.o
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:8:0:
j_as.h: In function ‘cpp11::sexp as_r(Json)’:
j_as.h:165:22: error: reference to ‘writable’ is ambiguous
             result = writable::list(j.size()); // default: NULL elements
                      ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:1:0:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:14:39: note: candidates are: namespace writable = cpp11::cpp11::writable;
 namespace writable = ::cpp11::writable;
                                       ^
In file included from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/list.hpp:10:0,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/data_frame.hpp:12,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11.hpp:7,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:13,
                 from rjsoncons.cpp:1:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/r_vector.hpp:44:11: note:                 namespace cpp11::writable { }
 namespace writable {
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:8:0:
j_as.h:169:22: error: parse error in template argument list
             result = j_as_r_vector<writable::logicals, bool>(j);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
j_as.h:173:22: error: parse error in template argument list
             result = j_as_r_vector<writable::integers, int32_t>(j);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
j_as.h:177:22: error: parse error in template argument list
             result = j_as_r_vector<writable::doubles, double>(j);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
j_as.h:181:22: error: parse error in template argument list
             result = j_as_r_vector<writable::strings, std::string>(j);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
j_as.h:186:13: error: reference to ‘writable’ is ambiguous
             writable::list value(j.size());
             ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:1:0:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:14:39: note: candidates are: namespace writable = cpp11::cpp11::writable;
 namespace writable = ::cpp11::writable;
                                       ^
In file included from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/list.hpp:10:0,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/data_frame.hpp:12,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11.hpp:7,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:13,
                 from rjsoncons.cpp:1:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/r_vector.hpp:44:11: note:                 namespace cpp11::writable { }
 namespace writable {
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:8:0:
j_as.h:188:67: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
                 j.array_range().cbegin(), j.array_range().cend(), value.begin(),
                                                                   ^~~~~
j_as.h:188:67: note: suggested alternative: ‘valloc’
                 j.array_range().cbegin(), j.array_range().cend(), value.begin(),
                                                                   ^~~~~
                                                                   valloc
j_as.h:196:9: error: reference to ‘writable’ is ambiguous
         writable::list value(j.size());
         ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:1:0:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:14:39: note: candidates are: namespace writable = cpp11::cpp11::writable;
 namespace writable = ::cpp11::writable;
                                       ^
In file included from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/list.hpp:10:0,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/data_frame.hpp:12,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11.hpp:7,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:13,
                 from rjsoncons.cpp:1:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/r_vector.hpp:44:11: note:                 namespace cpp11::writable { }
 namespace writable {
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:8:0:
j_as.h:197:9: error: reference to ‘writable’ is ambiguous
         writable::strings names(j.size());
         ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:1:0:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:14:39: note: candidates are: namespace writable = cpp11::cpp11::writable;
 namespace writable = ::cpp11::writable;
                                       ^
In file included from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/list.hpp:10:0,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/data_frame.hpp:12,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11.hpp:7,
                 from /home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/declarations.hpp:13,
                 from rjsoncons.cpp:1:
/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/cpp11/include/cpp11/r_vector.hpp:44:11: note:                 namespace cpp11::writable { }
 namespace writable {
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from rjsoncons.cpp:8:0:
j_as.h:202:13: error: ‘names’ was not declared in this scope
             names[i] = it->key();
             ^~~~~
j_as.h:203:13: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
             value[i] = as_r(it->value());
             ^~~~~
j_as.h:206:9: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
         value.names() = names;
         ^~~~~
j_as.h:206:25: error: ‘names’ was not declared in this scope
         value.names() = names;
                         ^~~~~
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:200: recipe for target 'rjsoncons.o' failed
make: *** [rjsoncons.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rjsoncons’
* removing ‘/home/ignatius/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rjsoncons’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmppa0z3X/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rjsoncons", repos = "https://CRAN.R-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘rjsoncons’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Interesting. I got it to install from source in my mac. It compiled with `clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/cpp11/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c cpp11.cpp -o cpp11.o` (among others) using `4.2.1`. Maybe there are compiler/header differences.

Comment: [Update R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) and all your packages (`update.packages(ask=FALSE)`) then try again.

Comment: The OP posted an issue at https://github.com/mtmorgan/rjsoncons/issues/3 and an initial solution has been explored; this is related to https://github.com/r-lib/cpp11/issues/164 and a relatively old C++ compiler